# Docker on Windows 10: How to move existing containers & images to new location?

Tags: windows, docker, access-denied, docker-container, docker-image

I want to move my Docker containers & images from C: to elsewhere. All containers/images are Windows-ones.

I've changed the Docker data files location using the `data-root` configuration option, restarted the daemon and desktop client, and verified the data root location with `docker info`.

The problem is, that none of the existing containers & images are moved to the new location. Just the desktop client's configuration files. The desktop client doesn't seem to offer any means for (forcing/persuading it) moving the data to new location.

Tried to address the issue by manually copying `C:\ProgramData\Docker` contents to the new location, but everything sooner or later fails when copying special system files, such as `bootmgr`, inside images in `windowsfilter` (Running `robocopy` in elevated PowerShell or copying in Explorer, doesn't matter).

Is there any way around this, to move existing images & containers without breaking everything? I don't have a Linux machine at my disposal I could use to mount the NTFS volumes and do the copying there.

Comment: Hmm. I tried teracopy too, but it gets stuck. I wonder if a certain combination of robocopy options would help?

Comment: Also, this question is probably better suited to SuperUser

Answer (score 2):

I found that setting `data-root` would result in **new** images being created on the desired drive but existing images would continue to run from the system drive (C:\). I even tried deleting the windowsfilter folder on the C:\ drive but when running the container the images were re-downloaded to the C:\ drive instead of the configured data-root location.

The thing that worked for me was to perform a factory reset from the [troubleshooting menu](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/) (The [image: Bug icon] in docker desktop is a shortcut to this menu). This will clean up the windowsfilter folder in your system drive - However I had to run factory reset twice as the first time failed.

After reset has completed, go to `Settings->Docker Engine` and add a `data-root` entry folder on another drive:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": false,
  "experimental": false,           <-- remember to add a comma here
  "data-root": "E:\\dockerdata"
}
```

Then click `Apply & Restart`